# How to authenticate mongodb connection in robot framework

Tags: robotframework

I want to connect to MongoDB and query from MongoDB collection.
I have installed Mongodb by installing following libraries:

```
pip install pymongo
pip install robotframework-MongoDBLibrary
```

It installed properly.

after that i wrote the following statements in RIDE to query from mongodb

```
Connect to MongoDB    dbHost=${host}    dbPort=${port}
```

I just ran this statement, test script is pass.

Then to query, i have added one more statement as below:

```
${fields} =    Retrieve Mongodb Records With Desired Fields    ${MongoDBName}    ${MongoDBCollection}    {}    profileDetails.customerCategory.masterCode    return__id=False
```

after execution, i got the following error:

```
OperationFailure: database error: not authorized for query on clmpreprod.Profile
```

Normally, in java to connect to Mongodb we will follow the below steps

```
MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient(Arrays.asList(
                   new ServerAddress(MONGO_DBURL, 27017),
                   new ServerAddress(MONGO_DBURL, 27018),
                   new ServerAddress(MONGO_DBURL, 27019)));

DB database = mongoClient.getDB(MONGO_DBNAME);
boolean auth = database.authenticate(MONGO_USERNAME,MONGO_PASSWORD).toCharArray());
DBCollection collection = getCollection(MONGO_CUSTOMER_COLLECTION, database);
    List<DBObject> obj = collection.find(queryDBParams, returnDBParams).sort(sortDBParams).limit(1).toArray();
```

Can anyone help me what keyword or what series of steps need to follow to use in robotframework for database authentication and then query

Thanks
Sarada

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer in MongoDBLibrary documentation, here the link [RobotFramework-MongoDBLibrary](https://github.com/iPlantCollaborativeOpenSource/Robotframework-MongoDB-Library/blob/master/src/MongoDBLibrary/mongo_connection_manager.py)

Syntax is:

```
Connect To MondoDB | mongodb://admin:admin@192.20.33.226 | 27017 | 10 | None | <type 'dict'> | False |
```

Thanks
Sarada